# Testing method called with specific string

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to find answer to my question but unable to find something working. I have a class which does this

```
public class LambdaLoggerWrapper {

    public LambdaLoggerWrapper(LambdaLogger lambdaLogger){
        this.lambdaLogger = lambdaLogger;
    }

    public void logInfo(String caller, String message){
        lambdaLogger.log(message);
    }
}
```

and my test is

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LambdaLoggerWrapperTest{
    @Mock LambdaLogger mockLambdaLogger;

    @Test
    public void testLog(){
         LambdaLoggerWrapper llw = new LambdaLoggerWrapper(mockLambdaLogger);
         //how to test that calling llw.logInfo actually calls lambdaLogger.log with appropriate string?
    }
}
```

How would I test that calling llw.logInfo actually calls lambdaLogger.log with the appropriate string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the `logInfo()` method on the instance under test :

```
String message = "my message";
llw.logInfo("caller", message);
```

And use the `Mockito#verify()` method to assert that the mock was invoked with the expected method and with the parameter you have passed to the tested method :

```
Mockito.verify(lambdaLogger).log(message);
```

Comment: Indeed. Rather easy and your sample code was on the right way. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

```
final ArgumentCaptor<String> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {

     assertEquals("yourexpectedValue", argumentCaptor.getValue());
     return ;// return an instance of whatever type LambdaLogger::log method returns

}).when(mockLambdaLogger).log(argumentCaptor.capture());

llw.logInfo("caller", "yourexpectedValue");
```

If you are not using Java8 replace this with anonymous inner class.